# Wpdb get->results to out the the month from the db

Tags: php, loop, database, wpdb

I'm not getting the correct result from my attempt on creating a table with all the different months displayed and then how many the avg weight was for that month. THIS IS WHAT I'VE GOT:

Right now i use the `WHERE CLAUSE with which month it is manually, but i want it to more dynamic if its possible?

```
<table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
<tr align="left" valign="top">
    <td>MONTH</td>
    <td>Kilo</td>
<?php
global $wpdb;
$rows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT dato, avg(fiske_vaegt) as fiske_vaegt 
    FROM `wp_registreringer`
    WHERE MONTH(dato) = 11 AND YEAR(dato) = 2017;");

foreach ( $rows as $row ) {

    ?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $row->dato;?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row->fiske_vaegt;?></td>
```

OUTPUTS: 
There is of course only one month displayed, but then the output of the month needs to be formattet to only display the month like January and so on
[image]
So to sum up is it possible to create a select statement to dynamically take all records of all the month and display the correct month with the correct avg. amount of weight from my Database?

Comment: This doesn't seem WP specific to me if your table is custom? `$wpdb` essentially just executes your SQL in this scenario.

Comment: I see your point, i'm sorry this was probably better to ask on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `MONTHNAME(dato)` on your select Like

```
$rows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT MONTHNAME(dato) as month_name, avg(fiske_vaegt) as fiske_vaegt 
    FROM `wp_registreringer`
    WHERE MONTH(dato) = 11 AND YEAR(dato) = 2017;");
```

and access it like this `echo $row->month_name`

Comment: its not displaying anything but the weight number is showing

Comment: This should work. Are you using Mysql?

Comment: Yes im using Mysql. Maybe i'm not echoing it the write way? cuz its just blank.

Comment: You probably didn't update the Name so you can access it. The Select will return the Name of the month and the Average value. So I add an alias (month_name) to be able to access this value in the foreach loop

Comment: Sry but its not posting anything in that row

Comment: Can you print_r($wpdb->last_query); ? (After the run of the $wpdb->get_results)

Comment: `SELECT MONTHNAME(dato), avg(fiske_vaegt) as fiske_vaegt FROM wp_registreringer WHERE MONTH(dato) = 11 AND YEAR(dato) = 2017;
MONTH Kilo
9.90000`

Comment: See my previous comment and the updated answer as I write the correct use.